# Difference between php setting choices

Tags: php, settings

I have Parallels Plesk Panel.
I'm setting hosting account and php could be enabled in three ways

- Apache module
- FastCGI application
- CGI application

What is the difference and how it affects php work ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I'll save you some reading: just use FastCGI.  The Apache module is a security hole in a box, and CGI is slow.